# How can I close and seal an abandoned downspout opening?

Tags: gutters, downspout

I need to relocate the downspout indicated in the picture below. How do I seal the opening that will be left after I relocate it ? (I will post a separate question about how to redo the slope of the gutters)
The intent here is to discharge the water on my asphalt driveway (the city wants us to disconnect our downspouts from the main drain of the house-they have capacity issues)

[image]

Here is the link to the related post [I need to change the slope of my gutters. What do I need to know for this?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/101490/i-need-to-change-the-slope-of-my-gutters-what-do-i-need-to-know-for-this)

Update: I ended up connecting the downspout next to the opposite corner on the side visible in the picture, so there will be just one 90 there no matter which way you come  [image]
The downspout is attached to the wall on the face that is opposite to the one where it was located. I went with this option because I could not bend the downspout near the corner (too rigid). The side that I used already had the slope required for this.

Comment: What material are your gutters made of? Aluminum, plastic, copper?

Comment: It is aluminium

Comment: Aluminum is easy to seal with tar or asphalt calking. I am not a expert on roof drains but trying to go around this size structure may be problematic because of the distance and a few 90's.

Comment: Just one 90 no matter where you come from ... see the update for pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have covered over holes similar to this using thin aluminum sheet (and copper on copper gutters) bent to shape to fit the inside of the gutter and then pop riveted in place (after applying a little low modulus silicone sealant around the hole on the inside and along the outer edges of the repair section to stop water going in between.

It does of course squeeze out some sealant during the riveting process so you might need to use a paintable sealant if you're painting the guttering outside. The ones I've done have not been visible from the ground, luckily enough.

It's also possible to put the repair sheet on the outside of the guttering if you're careful, which may look neater to the eye.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing but I was looking for a possibly nicer solution. I did not manage to completely seal it so it leaked last night. I used 4 screws to fix it in place and they I use gutter sealant to cover the screws and the edges. I wish I had the idea to put some sealant on the perimeter of the opening before fixing the aluminium sheet in place.