# I need to change the slope of my gutters. What do I need to know for this?

Tags: gutters, downspout

My questions are at the bottom of the post

Here is the picture that shows what I am trying to do
[image]

The gutters are attached to the [image]

My questions:
-in order to correct the slope would it be enough just to reposition the same screws into new holes just above or belot the existing ones?
-the corners are made like in the picture below. I am affraid that while moving the joint gutters I might crack the sealing, what do I need to do to fix it properly ?
Here is a related post that might also help you what I am trying to do [How can I close and seal an abandoned downspout opening?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/101488/need-to-relocate-a-downspout-and-i-am-trying-not-to-replace-the-gutter-how-do-i)